# error: cannot find symbol super.replaceExistingNonRootView(oldTag, newTag);

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

getting error while building Android Project

```
 error: cannot find symbol
    super.replaceExistingNonRootView(oldTag, newTag);
```

Here's the Versions:

```
  "react-native": "0.74.0-rc.0",
  "react-native-reanimated": "3.7.0",
```

i tried to delete node_modules and reinstall node modules. also tried with clean project.